# error in clearing eclipse plugin console

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin

I am trying to clear eclipse plugin project console but whenever i run my code to clear, whole my project got hangs. please help me to find where i am doing wrong.
Here is the code for creating console

```
@Override
public void openConsole() {
    socConsole = createConsole1();
}

private IOConsole createConsole1() {

    // creating a console with title Welcome to SoC Console.
    IOConsole ioconsole = new IOConsole("Welcome to SoC Console.", null);
    // adding created console to console list in console view.
    ConsolePlugin.getDefault().getConsoleManager()
            .addConsoles(new IConsole[] { ioconsole });
    ConsolePlugin.getDefault().getConsoleManager()
            .showConsoleView(ioconsole);

    OPstream = ioconsole.newOutputStream();
    System.setOut(new PrintStream(OPstream));
    System.setErr(new PrintStream(OPstream));
    //System.out.print("SoC>");
    System.out.print("%");
    /*System.out.print("tcl%");
    TclConsole.tclShell=true;*/
    IOConsoleInputStream IPstream = ioconsole.getInputStream();
    System.setIn(IPstream);
    return ioconsole;
}
```

and here how i am clearing console

```
ConsoleFactory.socConsole.clearConsole();
```

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand what you are saying happens when you try to clear the console.

Comment: sorry its typing mistake..my project got hangs after run clear console function